# How to change oracle apex 5 item after dynamic action button clicked?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

This is for Oracle Apex 5.

I have a static content item on my login page, it has registration fields with a dynamic action button. Upon the click of the button their details are inserted into a table. I'd like the fields to disappear and 'registered. email verification sent' text to appear in that static content?

If that's not possible, is there a way for me to write that text underneath the registration fields and at the same time, clear all the fields - after button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you have a Static Content Region (not item) with some text as source and you want that text to change if so i suggest you add a Display Only Item inside the Static Content Region and in that Dynamic Action simply change the value of the item using pl/sql, javascript or Set Value Dynamic Action.

Edit: You can use [this plugin](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=654321:405::::::) to have a timer that will run a Dynamic Action to change the text.

Comment: Great idea. I'll try that out. Is there a way to put a timer on the how long the text is displayed?

Comment: maybe a little beginner-ish of me, how would you pl/sql a vlue into a field. I did begin :P101_displaytext := 'submitted' . It doesn't work. I mean how would you plsql values into a field? thank you.

Comment: You are using pl/sql correctly but you need to refresh the item so you can see the new value. For you i think it's recommended that you use a Dynamic Action to Set Value.

Comment: works perfect. Brilliant. Thank you. I love this site.